# Sunspot - search.results throws undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass

Tags: sunspot, sunspot-rails

I an using Sunspot and have the following code

```
search = UserSearchKeywords.search do
  fulltext "#{params[:search_keyword]}"
  adjust_solr_params do |params|
    params[:fl] = "user_profile_id"
  end
end
```

When I try to invoke the

```
search.results
```

method, I get the following exception

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `match' for nil:NilClass)
```

Can anybody please help me understand where am I making a mistake?

Regards,
Shardul.

Answer (score 2):

Add id columns in the fl list which will be your primary key for UserSearchKeywords table

```
params[:fl] = "id user_profile_id"
```